# Does sqlite need to scan all the database when using "select xx from table where a!=b limit 200, 1"

Tags: sqlite, select

My sqlite may store billions of rows of data.

The table looks like this:

```
        name VARCHAR(128),
        directory VARCHAR(128),
        prefix VARCHAR(128),
        crtime INTEGER,
        filesize  INTEGER
```

And I didn't create index for any sections.

I need to scan all the database to check whether filesize or crtime satisfy some conditions.

To improve scanning performance, I want to scan DB like this

```
select name 
from table 
where filesize < 100 
limit 200, 1
```

every 200 rows.

I'm not very familiar with sqlite, so I don't know whether sqlite will scan all the database if I use this SQL command.

And are there any more efficient methods?

Comment: Add an index on `table(filesize)`.

Comment: And read https://use-the-index-luke.com/ - it has a lot of useful information including on efficient pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Well, it will have to scan every row until it finds 201 that satisfy the condition.

SQLite is not an appropriate choice for a database with billions of rows.  SQLite was designed for convenience, not performance.  You need to use a real database server, like MySQL or Postgres.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I didn't choose mysql or PG just because I dont want to setup a standalone sql server. Do you have any advice for datebase like sqlite which can store billions of rows?

Comment: Yes.  MySQL and Postgres.  Seriously.  Setup a standalone server.  It's easy, and that's what they're for.